# Vue.js script does nothing in Laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-5.5

I'm tring to add new text field to an existing form when somebody clicks on the + sign.
This is working good in the code snippet that I created. But it's not working in my Laravel 5.5 site.

I don't have any errors in my console.

The HTML goes into create.blade.php and the vue script is into addFlavor.vue
I'n my app.js i put:

```
Vue.component('addflavor-component', require('./components/addFlavor.vue'));
```

```js
// addFlavor.vue
new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
        data() {
            return {
             formdata: [],
                flavors: [{
                    name: '',
                    percentage: '',
                }]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addAroma: function(){
                this.flavors.push({
                    name: '',
                    percentage: ''
                })
            }
        },
        
    })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<!-- create.blade.php -->
<div id="vue">
  
    <div class="form-row align-items-left" v-for="flavor in flavors">

        <div class="col form-inline">
            <label class="sr-only" for="flavorname">Aroma 1</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input  type="text" 
                        class="form-control mb-2 mb-sm-0" 
                        id="flavorname" 
                        v-model="flavor.name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group md-2 mb-sm-0">
                <input  type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        id="percentage" 
                        v-model="flavor.percentage">
                                
                <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb5" @click="addAroma">+</button>
        </div> 
</div>
  
  <hr>
  
  <pre>
    {{ $data | json }}
  </pre>
  
</div>
```

How can I use this script correctly in my Laravel 5.5 site?

Comment: see in network tab of the dev toools to check if there is some missing recources

Comment: I Don't see the addFlavor.vue there, but i guess thats oke.

Comment: When I move the HTML code to the template in the .vue file and add <addflavor-component></addflavor-component> into my create.blade.php I get the following error: app.js:32397 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <addflavor-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)

Comment: It means your .vue file is not loaded, vue cannot find the component.

Comment: simply put it in a .js file instead of .vue and include it at the footer normally

Comment: sorry I was forget to run watch. In Included now but I get:
**Property or method "flavors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render**

Comment: you are using the data method the wrong way, your properties should be in data object like this `data: { formatdata:[], flavors: {name:"", percentage: ""}}`, you are using data method which should be only used in components itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your file `addFlavor.vue` to `AddFlavor.vue` (to follow VueJS recommendations).

Change your code in that file to:

```
export default {
    name: 'add-flavor',

    data() {
        return {
            formdata: [],
            flavors: [{
                name: '',
                percentage: '',
            }]
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addAroma() {
            this.flavors.push({
                name: '',
                percentage: ''
            })
        }
    },
}
```

Change the code in `app.js` to

```
import AddFlavor from './components/AddFlavor.vue';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    components: {
        'addflavor': AddFlavor,
   }
});
```

Add the following line to `webpack.min.js`:
`mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');` and include the `app.js` in your blade layout file via `<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`.

Remove the manual VueJS import from your HTML file. Its not necessary since its already defined in package.json and will be installed via NPM. Furthermore, you import version 1.x of VueJS but the latest version is 2.5.x. I strongly recommend this one.

```
<!-- create.blade.php -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="vue"><!-- <-- This could go to your main layout file -->
    <add-flavor inline-template>
        <div class="form-row align-items-left" v-for="flavor in flavors">
            <div class="col form-inline">
                <label class="sr-only" for="flavorname">Aroma 1</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mb-sm-0" id="flavorname" v-model="flavor.name">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group md-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percentage" v-model="flavor.percentage">

                    <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb5" @click="addAroma">+</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </add-flavor>
    <hr>

    <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>

</div>
```

So said, if not already done, install all node dependencies via `npm install` or `yarn install` and afterwards run `node run watch`. This should build all needed modules.

Comment: I renamed the file to VueJS recommendations and change my AddFlavor.vue to your version. That was all whats needed. Thank you for your clear explenation. I'm using Vue,js 2.5.9. Must have imported the wrong file into the code snippet.